# Billing Address Same as Shipping Address jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am having trouble getting the Billing Address to copy over the Shipping Address using jQuery. I have successfully done this using a plain-jane form with no custom jQuery elements. But when I add the custom UI to the checkbox, it seems to break the code. I have tried several code changes but none of them are working.

When a user clicks on "My billing address is the same as my shipping address", nothing is happening. Here is my jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#check-address').click(function(){
        if($('#check-address').attr('checked')){
            $('#address-field1').val($('#address-field').val());
            $('#city-field1').val($('#city-field').val());
            $('#zip-field1').val($('#zip-field').val());
            var state = $('#state-field option:selected').val();
            $('#state-field1 option[value=' + state + ']').attr('selected','selected');
        } else { 
            //Clear on uncheck
            $('#address-field1').val("");
            $('#city-field1').val("");
            $('#zip-field1').val("");
            $('#state-field1 option[value=Nothing]').attr('selected','selected');
        };

    });
});
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**Demo of options**](http://jsfiddle.net/sRt6G/3/)

```
$('#check-address').attr('checked')
```

<s>should</s> could be

```
$('#check-address').is(':checked')
```

---

As pointed out in comments, there are many ways to skin this cat. http://jsfiddle.net/sRt6G/1/
`this.checked` seems to be the simplest.

Comment: Why should it be? It'll still work (although `prop('checked')` would be more *correct*. It's probably more efficient to use `attr()` over `is()` anyway.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have updated my code here: rushapassport.com/Secure/Final/application-step-3b.php but it still is not working for me. Any help?

Answer (score 5):

You are using jquery 1.7 . You should use prop instead of attr

```
  $('#check-address').prop('checked')



       $(elem).attr('checked')    // returned true (Boolean) prior to 1.6
        $(elem).attr('checked')   // now returns "checked" (string) versions after 1.6
        $(elem).prop('checked')    // now returns true (Boolean) versions after 1.6
```

Answer (score 5):

The plugin you're using to prettify your checkbox (or whatever it does), is replacing the `<input type="checkbox"/>` with a `div`, and *simulating* events on the checkbox.

It doesn't propagate a `click` event, but it ***does*** propagate a `change`, so you should listen for that instead;

```
$('#check-address').change(/* function */);
```

To improve your code you might want to substitute the check for `attr('checked')` with `prop('checked')`, but your code will still work regardless. Reasons for this are outlined on the jQuery documentation for `prop()`; http://api.jquery.com/prop

Comment: Hey Matt, will you please levitate on your code a little more? I would really appreciate it?

Comment: @three3: Going to the link you gave me redirects me to http://www.rushapassport.com/Secure/Final/

Comment: sorry about that. It has been fixed now. Please try again

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you're trying to go on a click event of a checkbox. Have you tried:

```
$('#check-address').on('change', function (e) {...
```

and

```
 if ($('#check-address').is(":checked")....
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help too.

```
$('input[name=city\\[' + this.value + '\\]]').val($('input[name=city\\[1\\]]').val());
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ugdgzj1n/)

Fill out the form on top, then use the check boxes to copy the values of the fields.

It works with dynamically created fields. If the form is hard-coded, replace `this.value` with the index of the field.

Comment: The problem was with triggering on the change of the checked-state. Not with actually copying the data.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna try the following code: 
$("input.billingAddress").on("change",function(){

```
            var val1 = $("input.street").val();
            var val2 = $("input.suitNumber").val();
            var val3 = $("input.city").val();
            if(this.checked)
            {
                $("input.streetb").val(val1);
                $("input.suitNumberb").val(val2);
                $("input.cityb").val(val3);
            }

            else
            {
                $("input.streetb").val("");
                $("input.suitNumberb").val("");
                $("input.cityb").val("");
            }

            });
```